# Root of exponential equation with Napier's number

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, euler-mascheroni-constant

I'm trying to find the roots of this equation:

$(x^2-1)e^x=0$

I know that I could solve at first:

$(x^2-1)=0$ which has

$x=_{+-}1$

Here is the problem, because I sketched the graph also with Geogebra and the roots (of the entire equation) are only $-1$ and $1$, but if solve the equation:

$e^x=0$ with $ln(e^x)$ I know that the $x$ of $e$ is $0$.

So should the roots be $-1,0,1$? Why are they only $-1$ and $1$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $e^x$ is never zero, so that factor won't give you any additional solutions. Indeed if you plug in $x=0$ you will get $-1$.

Comment: $e^0=1$, in fact $e^x\ne 0$ for any real $x$.

Comment: If you are trying to solve $e^x=0$, by taking $\ln$ of both sides, remember that $\ln 0$ is undefined.